# Why is it showing undefined, if handleChange itself has values

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest

I'm trying to make a post request with the completed fields to the restapi, there are the parent component, in which I have my handleChange and formHandler. Below that is the child component, when I press submit it should make a post request with all the user data. First of all it's trying to make the post request before I press submit button, it's making it when I press continue from PersonalDetails to Confirm. So the question is why I get undefined from console logs and if someone could explain me how to make this post request to work would've been really nice.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StepOne from './StepOne';
import SocilaProfiles from './SocialProfiles'
import PersonalDetails from './PersonalDetails';
import Confirm from './Confirm';
import Success from './Success';
import axios from 'axios';

export class UserForm extends Component {
    state = {
        step: 1,
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
        twitter: '',
        facebook: '',
        googlePlus: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        phone: '',
        adress: ''
    }

    // Proceed to next step
    nextStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step + 1
        });
    }

    // Go back to prev step
    prevStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step - 1
        });
    }

    // Handle fields change
    handleChange = input => e => {
        let formFields = this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
    }

    // MAKING POST REQUEST TO THE API
    formHandler(formFields) {
        console.log('Form:')
        console.log(this.formFields)
        axios.post('/api', this.formFields)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                //Perform action based on response
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                //Perform action based on error
            });
    }


    render() {
        const { step } = this.state;
        const { email, password, confirmPassword, twitter, facebook, googlePlus, firstName, lastName, phone, adress } = this.state;
        const values = { email, password, confirmPassword, twitter, facebook, googlePlus, firstName, lastName, phone, adress };

        switch (step) {
            case 1:
                return (
                    <StepOne
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                    />
                )
            case 2:
                return (
                    <SocilaProfiles
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                        prevStep={this.prevStep}
                    />
                )
            case 3:
                return (
                    <PersonalDetails
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        prevStep={this.prevStep}
                        values={values}
                    />
                )
            case 4:
                return (
                    <Confirm
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        prevStep={this.prevStep}
                        values={values}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        formHandler={this.formHandler(this.state.formFields)}
                    />
                )
            case 5:
                return <Success />
                
        }
    }
}

export default UserForm;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../index.css';

export class Confirm extends Component {
    continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // PROCESS FORM -> SEND DATA TO API(EXPRESS)
        this.props.nextStep();
    }

    submit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.formHandler();
    }

    back = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    }

    render() {
        const { values: { email, password, confirmPassword, twitter, facebook, googlePlus, firstName, lastName, phone, adress }} = this.props;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.submit} className="msform">

                <fieldset>
                    <h2 className="fs-title"> Confirm Details </h2>
                    <hr/>
                    <ul className="theList">
                        <li> <strong>Email:</strong> {email} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Twitter:</strong> {twitter} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Facebook:</strong> {facebook} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Google Plus:</strong> {googlePlus} </li>
                        <li> <strong>First Name:</strong> {firstName} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Last Name:</strong> {lastName} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Phone:</strong> {phone} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Adress:</strong> {adress}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <input onClick={this.back} type="button" className="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
                    <input onClick={this.continue} type="submit" name="submit" className="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        );
    }
}


export default Confirm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you have a button of type "submit" in a form (or one that does not specifically say that its type is NOT "submit" by specifying a type of "button"),  the browser is going to view its click as the user wanting to submit the form. So the answer for your first question is simply to add `type="button"` to your continue button, instead of "submit".

You wrote a form handler override that tried to prevent the above, I don't see an obvious reason why it wasn't preventing it, actually.

Secondly, you seem to be trying to call your submit function by referencing `this.state.formFields`. However that does not exist in your state.  When you update your inputs, you are using this function:

```
    // Handle fields change
    handleChange = input => e => {
        let formFields = this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
    }
```

That `setState` call does not return values, it is a setter. You are setting an individual piece of your state (say, "name" equal to "John Doe")  And even if it did, your `formFields` would go nowhere.

Instead, in your submit function, you'll want to just pull the pieces out of  state that you are interested in. For instance,

```
const valuesToSubmit =  {
    name: this.state.name,
    email: this.state.email,
}
axios.post('/api', valuesToSubmit)
...
```